# sort categories by special condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I have variable, it contains categories

```
car bmw
car audi
car mers
vehicle mers
```

how to change the place?
all that contains key word `"mers"`
must be in first lines

i.e output

```
car      mers
vehicle  mers
car      bmw
car      audi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a dataframe and "mers" would always be present in 2nd column we can get indices where `V2` has "mers" in it and then concatenate the remaining indices

```
inds <- which(df$V2 == "mers")
df[c(inds, setdiff(1:nrow(df), inds)), ]

#   V1     V2
#3 car     mers
#4 vehicle mers
#1  car    bmw
#2  car    audi
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "car bmw
                         car audi
                         car mers
                         vehicle mers")
```